# Reading this C++ Marshalled Data in C# over UDP connection

Tags: c#, c++, marshalling

This structured data is being sent over a UDP connection. I can can read the UDP packets but I am having trouble with parcing the data that comes from this C++ Struct.

here is the Struct:

```
struct scanner_status{
    // ---
    u_short UDP_STATUS;
    u_short TCP_COMMAND;
    u_short TCP_LOGGING;
    // scanner attributes
    EPlatformModelNumber ModelNo;
    string SerialNo;
    bool bHasCT;
    bool bHasPET;
    bool bHasSPECT;
    // physical
    EBedType_mMM _eCurrBedType;
    int_16 _CurrPallet;
    bool _bTunnelPresent;
    //
    scanner_status()
      : UDP_STATUS(u_short(~0))
      , TCP_COMMAND(u_short(~0))
      , TCP_LOGGING(u_short(~0))
      , ModelNo(eUnknownPlatformModelNumber)
      , bHasCT(false)
      , bHasPET(false)
      , bHasSPECT(false)
      , _eCurrBedType(emMM_BedType_Unknown)
      , _CurrPallet(-1)
      , _bTunnelPresent(false)
    { }
};
decl_marshalling(scanner_status);
```

i would like to get help in reading this in C# and I am not really familiar with C++ and with marshalling, ao any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Presumably you have a `byte[]` with the raw data, correct? Have you looked at [`System.BitConverter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.aspx)? Padding is the one thing that complicates this, and without knowing the compiler and compiler _settings_ used to build the C++ code, we can only guess.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a similar structure in c# with equivalent .net types. You also need to decorate your c# structure as follows. Makes sure that the order is the same as in the c++ structure as you need to make sure that the memory layout is the same.

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
struct scanner_status{
// ---
[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U1)]
u_short UDP_STATUS;
[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U1)]
u_short TCP_COMMAND;
[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U1)]
u_short TCP_LOGGING;
```

Here is some help from Microsoft. [Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446538.aspx)

Let me know if you have still trouble.

Comment: `u_short` would be `UnmanagedType.U2`, not `UnmanagedType.U1`.